# Light Functions Weirdly On Nvidia Graphics Cards

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, lighting, light

EDIT: If you are curious about the game, you can inspect the game on steam: https://store.steampowered.com/app/2570900/SABAH_Sun_As_Biased_As_Harmony/

I have developed a video game on Unity. It works almost perfectly except weird light problem. I haven't seen any problem on AMD graphics cards (Tested on 2 different computers), but when I play my game on Nvidia GTX 1080, lights are going crazy. Why? How can I solve this problem? Thank you.
Here are the screenshots about the problem: (The sun is not purple! or the leaves of the tree are not purple! and on the last screenshot, there are no green or purple lights on the original map. There is a light problem!)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Those screenshots lighting should look like these (Correct Ones):
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it would help if you had shown the same screen shot from both cards  as there are 3 screen shots and none are marked as this is what you expected, or this is this what happened with nvidia. What pipeline are you using?

Comment: Thanks @BugFinder. I am uploading correctly lighted screenshots of the corrupted ones. These correct ones that comes from AMD Radeon 530 and Intel UHD 630 installed laptop computer. In addition of that, I tested the same project on AMD Radeon R7 240 installed desktop computer. And my project uses URP (Universal Render Pipeline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the problem. The source of the problem is Skybox. I have used Unity's Procedural Skybox shader to make my own skybox material. I have changed almost all values to make my own one, and main reason of this problem is Atmosphere Thickness values are going crazy when you increase over 3 or 4 or directly 5. My setting was 5. And that was creating the problem. I have reduced the value and that weird lighting solved. However, I want it to be 5, but you know that creates the problem on Nvidia. I haven't seen any problem on AMD. That's so stupid.

EDIT: I HAVE SOLVED THE PROBLEM. There is a falsy line on Unity's Procedurel Skybox Shader file. Open the .shader file and find this line:

```
#define kRAYLEIGH (lerp(0.0, 0.0025, pow(_AtmosphereThickness,2.5)))
```

and change it as this:

```
#define kRAYLEIGH abs((lerp(0.0, 0.0025, abs(pow(_AtmosphereThickness,2.5)))))
```

In this code, we are returning the absolute value. In this way, we are protecting the code returns negative values that causes the lighting problem in those screenshots. I guess, AMD handle those negative values better than Nvidia, so I haven't seen any problem on AMD. However, we have to return non-negative values, so we have used abs() function.

My skybox material's values:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not that uncommon to encounter graphics card-specific issues when using different AMD and Nvidia GPUs. Here are a few things you can do.

1. Update Graphics Drivers
2. Check if there are any shader compilation errors or warnings specific to Nvidia GPUs.
3. If possible, test your game on different Nvidia GPUs to see if the issue is specific to the GTX 1080
4. Verify that your shaders are compatible with the shader model supported by both AMD and Nvidia GPUs. Sometimes, using a lower shader model can improve compatibility.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try these. I hope, It works...